# Which OIDC solution?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I want to create an OAuth2-Service with OIDC.

Necessary features:

> -Single-Sign-On
>   -Multi-Factor-Authorisation (I want to authenticate a user over a mobile app when he is on the desktop computer)
>   -High Performance (Kubernet & Docker integration, Load-Balancing)
>   -multiple resource-servers (for different services) -> maybe there are different datase types necessary

Are there any easy or recommanded tutorials or recommendations? What should I do?

(Is it recommended to use mitreid or keycloak as a base? Should I expand Spring Oauth2?)

Answer (score 0):

Just write your UI and API cpde in a standards based manner and you will meet the above goals - it is not specific to any technology.

The first code sample in my blog at https://authguidance.com may help. Happy to answer follow up questions ..